# How to pass a named function as a parameter (scriptblock)

Tags: powershell, scriptblock

Let's take the classic first-order functions example:

```
function Get-MyName { "George" }

function Say-Hi([scriptblock]$to) {
  Write-Host ("Hi "+(& $to))
}
```

This works just fine:

```
Say-Hi { "Fred Flintstone" }
```

this does not:

```
Say-Hi Get-MyName
```

because Get-MyName is evaluated, not passed as a value itself.  How do I pass Get-MyName as a value?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to pass Get-Myname as a scriptblock, because that's how you've defined the variable type.

```
Say-Hi ${function:Get-MyName}
```

Comment: How is this different from `Say-Hi {Get-MyName}`? Is there a type other than `[scriptblock]` that would allow passing of named functions?

Comment: In this case, there is no difference, because the return value is the same as the scriptblock definition of the function. Which one are you wanting to pass, the scriptblock of the function or the return value from the invocation of that scriptblock?

Comment: I would like to pass the function itself, same as you can do in javascript, or any of the .net languages using delegates

Comment: OK.  We just did that.  The 'value' of a function is the content of it's script block.  In this case the script block is just "George".

Comment: That's not quite true, suppose `Get-MyName` took parameters, in your version you would have to know all the parameters that it is invoked with and forward them manually, if you're passing the function directly (as you would in js or c#) its parameters are whatever it is invoked with from inside `Say-Hi`

Comment: Then (get-item function:get-myname)

Comment: Ah, I see, and then I would have to get rid of the `[scriptblock]` constraint and it should work

Comment: I've never tried to pass a function that way, but the object type that returns is [functioninfo]. The scriptblock is just a property of the [functioninfo] object.

Answer (score 3):

If you are ready to sacrifice the `[scriptblock]` parameter type declaration
then there is one more way, arguably the simplest to use and effective. Just
remove `[scriptblock]` from the parameter (or replace it with `[object]`):

```
function Get-MyName { "George" }

function Say-Hi($to) {
  Write-Host ("Hi "+(& $to))
}

Say-Hi Get-MyName
Say-Hi { "George" }
```

So now `$to` can be a script block or a command name (not just a function but also alias, cmdlet, and script).

The only disadvantage is that the declaration of `Say-Hi` is not so self describing.
And, of course, if you do not own the code and cannot change it then this is
not applicable at all.

I wish PowerShell has a special type for this, see this [suggestion](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/863243/a-type-command-is-needed-to-combine-command-names-and-script-blocks).
In that case `function Say-Hi([command]$to)` would be ideal.

Answer (score 3):

This might be a better example to illustrate the question, and details of execution scope. @mjolinor's answer appears to work nicely for this use case:

```
function Get-MyName($name) { $name; throw "Meh" }

function Say-Hi([scriptblock]$to) {
  try {
      Write-Host ("Hi "+(& $to $args)) # pass all other args to scriptblock
  } catch {
      Write-Host "Well hello, $_ exception!"
  }
}
```

The command and its output:

```
PS C:\> Say-Hi ${function:Get-MyName} 'George'
Well hello, Meh exception
```

In particular, I'm using this pattern for wrapping functions that work with a flaky remote SQL Server database connection, which sleep, then retry several times before finally succeeding or throwing a higher exception.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly based on your code, the correct answer is this:

```
Say-Hi {(Get-MyName)}
```

This will produce "Hi George"

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any insight as to the difference between this syntax and that by @mjolinor above?

Comment: As @SamDevx said "strictly based on your code", there is not much difference. But if the function has parameters then calling it with parameters in this way will not be straightforward.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer The difference is that here is passed a new block in which `Get-MyName` is called. In mjolinor's example there is a direct reference to the `Get-MyName`-function passed. (With parameters this variation could be written like `Say-Hi { Get-MyName @args }` whereas mjolinor's would work without modification.)